# JQUERY and window resize

Tags: jquery, dom, twitter-bootstrap, resize, event-bubbling

this may seem a simple question regarding Jquery and twitter bootstrap

I have a twitter bootstrap, fluid layout,  when the windows resizes, the fluid rows obviously resize, but I notice these `<div>`s don't get or issue  `.resize` events

I can detect the browser windows resize useing `$(window).resize`, but even though the child elements resize , attaching a resize handler to them does not result in a resize event trigger

I know you might say that resize events only bubble 'up', but surely if div is resizing, due to the browser window resizing ( and via bootstrap CSS) it should get a resize event.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: fyi, if you're looking to use jQuery's resize on anything OTHER than `window`, you'll need a plugin like this one -> http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onresize), "Only the `window` object has an `onresize` event." So like it or not you just have to code accordingly. (It would be _nice_ if `textarea` elements also had a resize event, since (in some browsers) the user can resize them independent of other elements, but other element types resize only because the whole window does, so...)

Comment: *"...attaching a resize handler to them does not result in a resize event trigger..."* Right. There is no `resize` event for elements in general.

Comment: Yes thanks , I read thru that

Comment: thanks again, I kinda knew the answer but was seeing if there was a neat workaround, there isnt

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to simply put the `resize` handler on the `window` and deal with any resize related changes which are needed throughout the content of the page in that one handler.

Alternatively, you could trigger a custom event on your elements when the window is resized:

```
$(".resizer").on("customresize", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text($this.width());
});

$(window).resize(function(){
   $(".resizer").trigger("customresize"); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vs8Q8/

Comment: thanks, I was trying to partition the code so that I didnt have one hander, rather attaching a specific handler to the elements so affected ( mostly hidden divs)

Comment: You can create your own custom event and `trigger` it in the `window.resize`